# Docker dev environment doesn't allow command line commands

Tags: magento2, docker

I recently set up a magento2 dev environment with Docker as identified on magento.com. However after installing new extensions I cannot run setup:upgrade or static-content deploy.  Is this because of an internal domain name not being set or a db connection issues? Below are my CLI errors.

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodena  
  me nor servname provided, or not known 

 [Exception]                                                                  
  Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:   
  nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/devmac03/Desktop/mvp  
  /shared/webroot/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/A  
  bstract.php on line 129
```

Comment: are  you expose 3306 port in db docker machine ?

Comment: I just ran it through the 3 step process as identified on the site. Do you know how many additional steps there are? Otherwise I will just Google it. I appreciate your time.

Comment: which site  you follow to install magento2 in docker

Comment: https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/configure/

Answer (score 2):

You need access your container using:

```
docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME bash
```

To discover the name use `docker ps`.